# Grey screen after login GNOME, after using "prime-select intel"

Tags: gnome, 22.04, amdgpu, nvidia-prime

I have an Asus ROG laptop with a Ryzen 7 4800 CPU and an RTX 3060 GPU. My ubuntu version is 22.04

I have the kernel version 5.15.0-47 and I'm using the nvidia-driver-515.

I was able to switch between the nvidia dedicated gpu and the integrated amd gpu using the 'prime-select' command until today (09/07/2022)

I just installed some updates with "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt upgrade" and after rebooting, I can log in but the gnome desktop has a grey wallpaper and I cant click anything.

If I go into a tty with CTRL + ALT + F3 and log in, I can run "sudo prime-select query", the output is "intel".

So I switch to the nvidia card by running "sudo prime-select nvidia" and I reboot.

After that I'm able to log in, and "prime-select query" returns "nvidia". But the moment I do "prime-select intel" to reboot with the integrated GPU, I meet the grey screen after login again.

Ive been switching GPUs this way for years to save battery and I never had this problem. I have tried reinstalling gnome and uninstalling and reinstalling the nvidia driver. I have also tried disabling all gnome extensions, all of this without success.

Today after an update I did:

"sudo prime-select intel"
"sudo reboot"

What happened:

The computer rebooted and I was able to log into GNOME, but to a grey unclickable screen with the fans ramping up. I am unable to open terminals or perform any keyboard shortcuts except for tty (CTRL ALT F3). Entering "prime-select nvidia" in the tty and rebooting allows me to use my computer but with the nvidia gpu enabled.

What I expected to happen:

I expected to be able to log in with the integrated graphics card enabled and not having to force the dedicated graphics card to be able to get to a usable desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

It was because of a driver update from the [oibaf graphics drivers ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) that got installed and broke my system.

I edited /etc/apt/preferences with the lines:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

To set maximum priority for "official" ubuntu packages and then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

There were some conflicts. For example, I had to do:

```
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri --allow-downgrades
```

And then I tried upgrading again and rebooting and now I can switch between GPUs as expected.

I hope this helps someone. Bye!